changing model data from a view model class
I have the following view model class that simply takes a dependency for the model data struct passed into it from the View's initializer, like so:
import SwiftUI

struct MyModel {
    var pages: [Int] = []
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var model = MyModel()
 
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Content View")
                
                NavigationLink("Details") {
                    DetailView(viewModel: DetailViewModel(model: model))
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                print(model.pages)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    
    @State private var viewModel: DetailViewModel
    
    init(viewModel: @escaping @autoclosure () -> DetailViewModel) {
        _viewModel = State(wrappedValue: viewModel())
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Detail View")
            
            Button("add page") {
                viewModel.addPage()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Observable
class DetailViewModel {
    private var model: MyModel
    
    init(model: MyModel) {
        self.model = model
    }
    
    func addPage() {
        model.pages.append(1)
    }
}

The value of pages of the model's state variable in ContentView is not updated from the view model in the detail view (after pressing the "add page" button). I know that I can do it easily using Binding between the 2 views, but I want to change the value using the view model, is there a clean way to do it ?
p.s. the code compiles, you may copy-paste it to try in XCode.

In SwiftUI the View structs are the view model already, you shouldn't have classes for it or will run into major issues.

State should always be private I suggest looking at the documentation you need Bindable

@malhal if that's true, then why Apple uses @Observable protocol for classes that should be used in SwiftUI views and they already implemented this approach in their code samples ? Using an Observable or ObservableObject classes with views is a very natural approach, we have a number of large projects that use this pattern with zero issues.

@loremipsum it's already private, I don't need to use@Bindable because I don't want to pass a modifiable copy of DetailViewModel

@JAHelia Apple have said many times use View structs for view data and ObservableObject or @Observable for models. But I understand structs are unfamiliar and many haven't learned mutating func.

Currently every time you navigate to DetailView you create a new DetailViewModel that has no relations to any other model.
To observe any changes to your models,
try this approach where you have one source-of-truth for your data,
DetailViewModel that you pass to DetailView.
See also Managing data  and in particular Data source
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var viewModel = DetailViewModel(model: MyModel())
 
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Content View")
                NavigationLink("Details") {
                    DetailView(viewModel: viewModel)
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                print("-----> pages count: \(viewModel.model.pages.count)")
                viewModel.model.pages.forEach {
                    print("-----> pages: \($0)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var viewModel: DetailViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Detail View")
            Button("add page") {
                viewModel.addPage()
            }
        }
    }
}


@Observable class DetailViewModel {
    var model: MyModel
    
    init(model: MyModel) {
        self.model = model
    }
    
    func addPage() {
        model.pages.append(1)
    }
}

struct MyModel {
    var pages: [Int] = []
}

EDIT-1:
If you don't want to use a view model for both views, then try this approach,
where you declare @Observable class MyModel ... and pass it to the DetailViewModel
in the .onAppear{...}.
Example code
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var viewModel = DetailViewModel(model: MyModel())
    @State private var model = MyModel()
 
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Content View")
                NavigationLink("Details") {
                    DetailView(viewModel: viewModel)
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.model = model
                model.pages.forEach {
                    print("-----> model.pages: \($0)")
                }
                viewModel.model.pages.forEach {
                    print("-----> viewModel.model.pages: \($0)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var viewModel: DetailViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Detail View")
            Button("add page") {
                viewModel.addPage()
            }
        }
    }
}


@Observable class DetailViewModel {
    var model: MyModel
    
    init(model: MyModel) {
        self.model = model
    }
    
    func addPage() {
        model.pages.append(1)
    }
}

@Observable class MyModel {
    var pages: [Int] = []
}


I don't want to use a view model for both views, my question is that I want to read the latest value from the model myModel from ContentView, which is changed through a view model in the child view

updated my answer to cater for having myModel from ContentView changed through a view model in the child view.

This is not what I want. I want the myModel to be a struct (not observable class), and we should use one variable for myModel to be shared between content view and the child view's view model

@JAHelia A simple struct is value type. When you pass it as a parameter in a function - even in a closure - it gets copied. It seems you’re fighting the framework. Please take workingdog’s advice and use one source of truth.

This leaks DetailViewModel objects because @State inits its initial value every time the View is init. Fine for stack values and structs, but a big problem for heap objects.

Structs can contain funcs, e.g.
struct MyModel { // normally this would be named Content when in a ContentView
    var pages: [Int] = []

    mutating func addPage() {
        pages.append(1)
    }
}

To get write access to @State use @Binding, e.g.
struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var model: MyModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Detail View")
            Button("add page") {
                model.addPage()
            }
        }
    }
}

Use $ syntactic sugar to call the @State's projected value which returns a Binding struct that contains get and set closures to read and write the value. Calling a mutating func on a struct is same thing as calling the set and changing the value.
@State private var model = MyModel()
...
DetailView(model: $model) // generates Binding(get:set:)


Thanks for the answer, but this solution eliminates the need for a view model to hold the data object + business logic based on that model, putting that business inside the model itself is an interesting idea but it's not my current scope of requirement.

As I've said previously, View structs are the view model already and use let for static data and @State for dynamic data (as structs with mutating funcs for testable logic)

did you find issues in large SwiftUI apps using this approach ? "using the model as the source of truth for the view and getting rid of view models" and where exactly can we use Observable or ObservableObject classes ?

You aren't getting rid of view models, SwiftUI IS a view model framework, ie the View structs are view models already. The only difference is they are structs for performance and to prevent consistency bugs. In a big app it's best to make the View structs as small as possible for faster diffing. SwiftUI diffs the View structs on every change and uses the difference to init/update/deinit UIKit objects in the layer beneath. Eg Text updates a UILabel, even updates it when region settings change.

Edited prev comment with more info

I got your idea that the view itself is a piece of view elements plus the model struct that feeds this view, and the business logic can be fit inside this model struct as needed. But my question is: where do you find it best fit to use @Observable / ObservableObject classes in a SwiftUI app.

Those are for your data models. Watch Luca's section from 9:24 in Data essentials in SwiftUI (WWDC 2020) https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10040?time=564 where he makes the distinction State is for view data, Observable is for data model.

thank you for the video, check this out as this talks about almost the same concept: https://blog.stackademic.com/removing-the-m-from-mvvm-with-swiftui-a58b239e9e3e  and check its github repo, the code is amazing
